# Toggle function to user added li

Tags: javascript, css, toggle

So, keeping it to the point. The code works fine and i am keeping it simple for now.

- Need to apply "toggle" class "done" to the user added "li".

```js
var userInput = document.getElementById("data");
var button = document.getElementById("btn");
var ul = document.querySelector("ul");

button.addEventListener("click", function(){
    if(userInput.value.length > 0){
        var li = document.createElement("li");
        li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(userInput.value));
        ul.appendChild(li);
        userInput.value = "";
    }
});
    
userInput.addEventListener("keypress", function(){
    if(userInput.value.length > 0 && event.which === 13){
        var li = document.createElement("li");
        li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(userInput.value));
        ul.appendChild(li);
        userInput.value = ""; 
    }
});
```

```css
.done {
    text-decoration: line-through
}
```

```html
<h1>Shopping List</h1>
<input id="data" type="text" placeholder="Enter items">
<button id="btn">Add item</button>
<ul>
</ul>
```

Comment: so when will the toggle class need to be added? when the user clicks the li?

Comment: @Michael Mano Yes. When the user click the ones added. toggle class gets added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.

```js
var userInput = document.getElementById("data");
var button = document.getElementById("btn");
var ul = document.querySelector("ul");

button.addEventListener("click", function(){
    if(userInput.value.length > 0){
        var li = document.createElement("li");
        li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(userInput.value));
        ul.appendChild(li);
        userInput.value = "";
    }
});

userInput.addEventListener("keypress", function(){
    if(userInput.value.length > 0 && event.which === 13){
        var li = document.createElement("li");
        li.addEventListener('click', function() {
        if (li.classList.contains('done')) {
            li.classList.remove('done');
            } else {
                li.classList.add('done');
            }
        });
        
        li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(userInput.value));
        ul.appendChild(li);
        userInput.value = ""; 
    }
});
```

Comment: Getting error here. script.js:20 Uncaught TypeError: li.classList.include is not a function
    at HTMLLIElement.<anonymous> (script.js:20)

Comment: fixed example. mistook includes with contains

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to make use of the `toggle()` feature provided by [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).

```js
document.querySelectorAll('li').forEach(function(li){
  li.addEventListener('click', function(){
    this.classList.toggle('done')
  })
})
```

```css
li{
  background: blue
}

li.done{
  background: red
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>line 1</li>
  <li>line 2</li>
  <li>line 3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't clearly what you are trying to do but if you want to give user a option to mark it done than you need  to bind event listners to li with 'click' event and that callback you can toggle the class

```js
    var li = document.querySelector(li");

    li.addEventListener("click", function(){
        // toggle logic
    }) ;
```

Comment: Trying to apply toggle function to the user added li so that the class done switches on and off if clicked on li

Comment: I mentioned the same thing about adding eventlister to li